# Add Attribute to First Element in For Loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm wondering how to add an "act" class to the first element in the following for loop?

```
if (!isset($this->params['page'])){
                $this->params['page'] == 1;
            }
             for($i=1; $i< $news_cont['response']['pager']['total_page']+1; $i++) {
                 if (isset($this->params['page']) && $this->params['page'] == $i){
                     $act = 'class="act"';
                 }else{
                     $act = '';
                 }
             echo '<a href="/' . $this->params['lang'] . '/' . $this->params['action'] . '/' . $i . '" ' . $act . '>' . $i . '</a>';
             }
```

I need it when `$this->params['page']` is not isset the first for cycle element have act class, else class "act" is defined to the element matching `$this->params['page']` Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  for($i=1; $i< $news_cont['response']['pager']['total_page']+1; $i++) {
    echo '<a href="/' . $this->params['lang'] . '/' . $this->params['action'] . '/' . $i . '" ' . ((($i == 1) && (!isset($this->params['page'])) ) ? 'class="act"' : '') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
  }
```

Comment: Hm, instead of pages numbers I'm getting class="act"class="act"

Comment: please be more specyfic, where you get it and what are pages numbers ?

Comment: `$i` is a page number `$this->params['page']` is a page number from url while page number is not clicked this parameter in url is empty, so at that moment I need that firfst page number has a class "act". So in your code instead a page number I got `class="act"class="act"`

Comment: `echo (($i == 1) && (!isset($this->params['page'])) ) ? 'class="act"' : '';` will render class="act or nothin if $this->params['page'] is not set or $i <> 1. so how it's possible you have double class="act"class="act" ?

Comment: I have two pages (1 2) instead of these numbers I'm getting (class="act"class="act")

Comment: OK, there was missing bracked wrapping if statment. I have corrected it, please test :)

Comment: Yep it's working fine now :) but I also need when I click on a page it have act class, (if $i == $this->params['page']) , now then I click on a page any number hasnt class act

EDIT: SOlved this by adding additional if statetment. Thanks!

Comment: make it simpler first... I have tested and I have expected output code: `$params = null;

for($i=1; $i< 3; $i++) {
  echo '<a href="/' . $i . '" ' . ((($i == 1) && (!isset($params['page'])) ) ? 'class="act"' : '') . '>' . $i . '</a>';
}` output : `<a href="/1" class="act">1</a><a href="/2" >2</a>` is this what you expect ?